# control rig best practice

Tags: rigging, armature, bones

I've spent a few weeks going through some excellent tutorial videos and have created a simple, rigged character. I'd now like to add some controllers using bones with custom object
**What is the best way to create the control bones to get them all into the same armature?** That's the case if they should be in a separate collection. When I create new bones, they go into their own armature. When I extrude or duplicate character bones they go into the character armature.

Many thanks.